# New HDD is "clicking" HTS721010A9E630 1TB Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

I have question related with my new HDD - is it normal that it "clicks"?

I pickup my notebook from RMA (they changed old HDD), and I noticed that it make sometimes weird sound (mostly when I turn computer ON, and for some time after that).

It happens randomly, mostly in ~30s series. Its brand-new second drive - so basically there is no data on it. It happen not only in Windows, but also I noticed it when OS was booting

SMART:
[HDTUNE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcJfU.png)

I also recorded how it clicks with my phone: https://my.mixtape.moe/enttli.m4a

edit - this question is different @burgi, because my disk is operating normally, have normal IO speed, no SMART errors....

Comment: Don't use it, and get that drive replaced! It's commonly referred to as a Click of Death, and is an indication of a read/write head crashing into one of the platters. Alternatively, it could be one of the reasons listed on this page https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=197 but I'd just get that drive swapped out to be on the safe side.

Comment: This could be just a head parking, a safety and energy saving measure. Although I'm not sure if Hitachi drives have this. You could ask vendor about it.

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not a normal sound.

They might have replaced it with a used one, or a bad new one. Either way, that drive should be replaced to prevent data loss.

Mechanic, distinct sounds from harddrives is usually a bad sign.

S.M.A.R.T might not detect these kinds of errors either, especially not if the drive seems to work properly according to speed and failrates.

Comment: Some drives do make fairly loud sounds normally as they work especially more heavily to clarify this that there are sounds that can be normal. But definitely agree this sound doesn't sound like those sounds and would do a replacement after talking to manufacturer and they agree its not normal.